# Syntax errors when placing php code containing quotation marks inside an HTML tag

Tags: php, html

Getting syntax errors when trying to replace hard coded url value below

```
<a class="cta cta-blue" href="http://example.com/book-now.html">Book your free consultation</a>
```

with URL that is generated dynamically through PHP code

```
<?php echo token_replace("[site:jc-book-now-url]"); ?>
```

Unfortunately, below does not work due to a mixup with quotation marks

```
<a class="cta cta-blue" href="<?php echo token_replace("[site:jc-book-now-url]"); ?>">Book your free consultation</a>
```

Comment: There is nothing in your posted code that would result in a syntax error. Is this your exact code? Is this code already in an `echo`?

Comment: Please edit your question asap.  Otherwise it will be closed as "Cannot be Reproduced".

Comment: Hi Sean, yes echo should return url into the href tag. This is the exact code. Somehow this is not working though...

Comment: If you are positive, no syntax errors are present and thre is nothing wrong with code - i will delete this post

Comment: I mean, have you tried using single quotes in your php? Seems unlikely as double quotes should work, but give it a shot anyway?. Alternatively use the single quotes on the href, and leave PHP with double.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you're having issues with
`<a class="cta cta-blue" href="<?php echo token_replace("[site:jc-book-now-url]"); ?>">Book your free consultation</a>`

There are different ways of doing this but my preferred method is:

Use single quotes
`<a class="cta cta-blue" href="<?php echo token_replace('[site:jc-book-now-url]'); ?>">Book your free consultation</a>`
or
`<a class="cta cta-blue" href='<?php echo token_replace("[site:jc-book-now-url]"); ?>'>Book your free consultation</a>`

Ultimately, this is up to you! Any one of the aforementioned options will work...

Comment: Number #1 should **never** be required and will trigger a syntax error. Number #2 is irrelevant

Comment: I wasn't prioritizing them by style, I was simply giving an answer that will prevent a syntax error.

Comment: I realize; it wouldn't cause a syntax error in other context's but in this, it does because it is within an HTML attribute. Thank you for correcting me.